# hiding classes with this and not?

Tags: jquery

Currently I'm work on a menu list to help me improve with jQuery, however I've come across a problem. I'm certain I should be able to use **this** function to select the item and .not() to hide the items not required

I placed it in a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/x19L1pwt/

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
            <h4>Menu</h4>
            <button class="vegetarian">Vegetarian</button><button class="fish">Fish dishes</button><button class="meat">Meat Dishes</button><button id="all">Show all</button>
            <ul class"menu">
                <li class="meat">Hamburger</li>
                <li class="fish">Smoked Salmon</li>
                <li class="vegetarian">Miso-grilled aubergine & cucumber pickle rice bowl</li>
                <li class="meat">Steak</li>
                <li class="fish">Fish and Chips</li>
                <li class="vegetarian">Aubergine parmigiana with crispy breadcrumbs</li>       
            </ul>    

    </div>    

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this).find("class");
        $this.not($this).hide();
        console.log($this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few errors with your code, and a couple of things that needed to be added. I have a working example below. My changes:

1. You were missing an equal sign in `<ul class"menu">`.
2. You were using jQuery [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to try to get the `class` of your clicked element. Instead, you can use `attr()` to get an attribute of an element. I set that class to a variable called `selection`.
3. On click of the button, I first `show()` all `li` elements, to restore any that were hidden during previous clicks in case we need to show them again.
4. Then I check if `selection` is set to anything. In the case of clicking the classless "Show all" button, it won't be. If the variable is set, it means you've clicked one of the food category buttons, so...
5. `$('.menu').find('li').not('.' + selection).hide();` - We select all `li` elements, then subtract the ones that aren't part of our class using `not()` and hide those.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {

    // get class attribute of clicked button
    var selection = $(this).attr('class');

    // show all items
    var $items = $('.menu').find('li');
    $items.show(); 

    // if the clicked button had a class...
    if (selection) { 

      // hide our items that do not have that class
      $items.not('.' + selection).hide();

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <button class="vegetarian">Vegetarian</button>
  <button class="fish">Fish dishes</button>
  <button class="meat">Meat Dishes</button>
  <button id="all">Show all</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="meat">Hamburger</li>
    <li class="fish">Smoked Salmon</li>
    <li class="vegetarian">Miso-grilled aubergine & cucumber pickle rice bowl</li>
    <li class="meat">Steak</li>
    <li class="fish">Fish and Chips</li>
    <li class="vegetarian">Aubergine parmigiana with crispy breadcrumbs</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense.  Thank you :)